# java nio iterate files in symbolic link

Tags: java, nio, symlink, unc

I would like to iterate over files that are in network UNC path so that I can operate over them, is it possible?

I'm trying in below way(see the  below code) and it's not listing the files.

But, with windows explorer I can access that folder and I can see, modify even remove them.

```
// created with this command: mklink /D C:\Users\user\Desktop\repo \\serverIp\public\repo
File repo = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\repo"); // symlink

final Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(repo.getCanonicalPath());

Files.walkFileTree(dir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path newDir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(newDir.toAbsolutePath());                
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(file.toAbsolutePath());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

Did I create the symbolic link correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use [FOLLOW_LINKS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html#FOLLOW_LINKS) option.

```
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
Files.walkFileTree(dir, EnumSet.of(FOLLOW_LINKS), Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() { ... ))
```

Comment: Not working if the root directory is symbolic link... maybe it will work if i put in another folder and then as a subfolder to that root folder it will follow the symlink but what i need is not this way

Comment: @EmrahMehmedov Can you please check if your link exists? something like `Files.isSymbolicLink(Paths.get())` and `Files.exists(Paths.get(..))`

Comment: For me it worked being the root directory a symbolic link.